# Execute WHILE loop takes longer and stuck Managment studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to execute 3 stored procedures in a `WHILE` loop. So first I look for data I need as:

```
DECLARE @FBOMDesigns AS TABLE
(
      DesignKey INT,
      ParentDesignKey INT,
      ProjectKey INT,
      CurrentRow INT
)

INSERT INTO @FBOMDesigns
    SELECT 
        D.DesignKey, [D].ParentDesignKey,
        [PD].[ProjectKey],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY D.[DesignKey]) AS [CurrentRow]
    FROM 
        ##Design AS D  
    INNER JOIN 
        ##ProjectDesign AS PD ON D.DesignKey = PD.DesignKey
    WHERE  
        DesignTypeGuid = '13B58AC4-F8BD-431F-8977-BE9C1FF25C7C'

DECLARE @NewCDDesigns AS TABLE 
(
     DesignKey INT,
     CurrentRow INT
)

INSERT INTO @NewCDDesigns
    SELECT 
        D.DesignKey,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY D.DesignKey) AS CurrentRow
    FROM 
        ##Design AS D
    INNER JOIN 
        ##ProjectDesign AS PD ON D.DesignKey = PD.DesignKey
    INNER JOIN 
        @FBOMDesigns as FD ON PD.ProjectKey = FD.ProjectKey
    WHERE 
        PD.ProjectKey IN (SELECT ProjectKey FROM @FBOMDesigns) 
        AND D.DesignTypeGuid = '54FBBC23-CB9A-4311-9D7F-0DD7A774F33D' 
        AND D.Folio = 0
```

As you can see I create two tables with information

Once I have it I set while variables:

```
DECLARE @counter   INT = 1,
        @max       INT = 0,
        @DesignKey INT

SET @max = (SELECT COUNT(DesignKey) FROM @NewCDDesigns)
```

Note: `@max` value is 628

So loop need to pass 628 times:

```
WHILE @counter <= @max
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CurrentDesignKey INT = (SELECT TOP 1 DesignKey FROM @NewCDDesigns 
                                     WHERE [CurrentRow] = @counter)
    DECLARE @CurrentPreviousDesignKey INT = (SELECT TOP 1 DesignKey FROM @FBOMDesigns 
                                             WHERE ParentDesignKey =  (SELECT TOP 1 DesignKey FROM @NewCDDesigns WHERE [CurrentRow] = @counter))\
    EXEC [copyPreviousDesign]
        @DesignKey = @CurrentDesignKey  ,
        @PreviousDesignKey = @CurrentPreviousDesignKey

    EXEC [copyCustomersFromPreviousDesign]
        @DesignKey =@CurrentDesignKey ,
        @PreviousDesignKey = @CurrentPreviousDesignKey

    EXEC [addDefaultTasksToDesign]
        @DesignKey =  @CurrentDesignKey
END
```

The problem is query took too much time, SQL Server Management Studio is stuck at minute 29 and I need to force close. Is there any way to do it more fast?

Comment: *"Is there any way to do it more fast?"* Yes, don't use a `WHILE` loop. SQL Server is designed for set based operations, not interative, so it performs well at the former and poorly at the latter. If you can explain what your actual goal is here we can help you turn what you have into a set based process.

Comment: You also have top 1 with no order by. Does it not matter which row you get?

Answer (score 2):

You have to increase @counter inside the while loop. It's an infinite loop.

select @counter = @counter + 1;

Comment: While this is the answer to the problem it only identifies that using a loop here is a poor way of handling data.